# Simple nginx redirect .php to home page

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, nginx

My old website had urls like:

domain.com/search.php?query=query
domain.com/product.php?id=id

I need to redirect requests to these files (and only these files) to:

domain.com

I'm using the Laravel framework that uses a single index.php file.

I've tried:

-Placing files named "search.php" and "product.php" in my root directory that redirects the user.

-Adding to Nginx conf:

```
location /search.php {
    return 301 http://domain.com;     
)
```

Comment: location ~ /search.php {
    return 301 http://domain.com;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your configuration file has a regex location for `.php` files, such as `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`. The regex location takes precedence over prefix locations, unless the `^~` modifier is used.

You have three options: use an exact match location `location =`, use a regex location, or use the `^=` modifier on a prefix location.

To match two URIs, I might be inclined to use a regex:

```
location ~* ^/(search|product)\.php {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/;
}
```

Make sure it is placed above the `location ~ \.php$` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.